# React: passing json values to react classes

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx

**Warning: Long post and I am new to react.**

**Scenario:** I want to create a bootstrap dropdown menu.  Some items in the dropdown menu will have submenus.

**Issue**: I am unsure how to pass a json values into another react variable.

**Javascript Object:**

```
var linksNav = {
    items: [
        {
            "type": "link",
            "title": "Events",
            "href": "#",
            "target": "_self"
        },
        {
            "type": "link",
            "title": "Groups",
            "href": "#",
            "target": "_self",
            "dropdown": 
                {
            "dropItems":
                    [
                        { 
                        "left": "First left submenu", 
                        "left-option": ["1","2"] 
                        },
                        { 
                        "left": "Second left submenu", 
                        "left-option": ["1","2"] 
                        },
                        { 
                        "left": "Third left submenu", 
                        "left-option": ["1","2"] 
                        }

                    ]
                }
        },

    ]
}
```

**To create the navigation bar**, I create a navigation variable:

```
var Navme = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
         var items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < linksNav.items.length; i++) {
            items.push(<LinksNav key={i} isDropdown = {linksNav.items[i].dropdown} type={linksNav.items[i].type} title={linksNav.items[i].title} href={linksNav.items[i].href} target={linksNav.items[i].target} />);
        }
        return (
<div className="zone">
<nav className="navbar navbar-default blade-nav">
<div className="container-fluid">

  <div className="nav-wrapper collapse navbar-collapse">

          {items}

  </div>
  </div>
</nav>

            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

**My LinksNav react variable is here**, this is also where it looks for a dropdown json key and if it finds it, it will include the `navDrop` variable (which has my dropdown menu) with my navigation menu item:

```
var LinksNav = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

     let navDrop;        
    if (this.props.isDropdown) {
      navDrop = (
        <ul className="dropdown-menu fade">
        <Navsub />
          </ul>
      )
    }
        return (

            <li className={this.props.title + ' nav-items'}>

             <a href={this.props.href} target={this.props.target} className={this.state.color + ' dropdown-toggle'} onClick={this.onClick} data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{this.props.title}</a>



  {navDrop}   


            </li>

        );
    }
});
```

**This is my dropdown menu.**  This is the part where I am stuck.  This is my Navsub class which is the UI for my bootstrap dropdown menu. I want to pass the values in my `isDropdown` object which I have from `LinksNav` class into this class and iterate through it to get my dropdown items.

I tried passing my isDropdown object as seen below: `this.props.isDropdown.dropItems.length`, but I recieved an error that dropItems is undefined.

```
  var Navsub = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var items = [];
        var rightItems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.props.isDropdown.dropItems.length; i++) {
            items.push(<Navsubleftitems key={i} type={this.props.isDropdown.dropItems[i].left} />);
        }

        return (
            <div className="group-dropdown-menu">
            <div className="dropdown-left-menu">
            {items}
            </div>
             <div className="dropdown-right-menu">
            {rightItems}

            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: you need to implement recursively loop

Comment: `Navsub` isn't being passed any props. It's being rendered as `<Navsub/>`. Pass it the drop items.